# How to avoid the 6 character minimum edit limit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, character-limit, limits

I recently found a piece of PHP code on Stack Overflow that was missing a semicolon. This would cause a syntax error, which in turn would cause a "500 internal error", and could be very confusing to beginners.

However, when I went to edit the post, I got an error:

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

What is the correct way to avoid this limit, when the change to be done is genuinely less than 6 characters? (as in this case, it was a single semicolon; I ended up just commenting about it)

Comment: You did what you could - just comment on it.  The OP can then edit it.

Comment: Couldn't you find something else that can be improved in that post?

Comment: @Eran Not that equals to 6 characters, not even with the formatting problem, can you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30054533/1067003

Comment: Check the edits I've made in your question here; there's almost always something else that can be improved.

Comment: @hanshenrik btw, the missing semicolon isn't actually a problem there.

Comment: Actually there was much to fix there, the code wasn't formatted at all. anyway, @Yannis already edited, and we can't see what's wrong.

Comment: I haven't found this here or in the original question, so: You can add an invisible html-comment to overcome that limit. In a second edit you could remove the comment again.

Comment: You can add an invisible HTML comment (`<!---->`) at the end of the post. That comment is 7 characters, so it's enough to get around the 6 character limit.